# prevent user from back after session is closed

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I'm trying to prevent user from back after session is closed. but its not working. any one suggest me how to do this.

In log out action class i wrote this code

```
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            mySession.removeAttribute("user_id");
            mySession.invalidate();

            return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
```

so it redirects user to index page. while i'm pressing back button it going back and user is able to see all pages which are already visited.

how to prevent this.

in every jsp page i'm trying like this

```
       if (session.getAttribute("user_id") == null || session.getAttribute("user_id").equals(""))
          {
                  response.sendRedirect("index.do");
           }            
           else
        {
             .........
        }
```

even though i'm not able to prevent user getting back. when ever user perform any action then only user redirects to index. help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is using Filter, that proccess every request to your application.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/547172/Struts/filters-struts

example of using filter for validation user session.

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if (req.getSession().getAttribute("user_id") == null || req.getSession().getAttribute("user_id").equals("")) {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.addHeader("Location", "/SessionTimeoutAction.do");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
        }


        chain.doFilter(request, res);
    }
```